# Fiddler: Can I intercept a specified request, with a specific referrer, and return a local file?

Tags: http, fiddler

I wish to add a Fiddler script that intercepts a http requests that matches both a specific location and a specific referrer, and responds with a local alternative.

Imagine we are looking for the following criteria:

**[IF]** request is for `www.domain.com/file.js` **[AND]** request has a referrer with the hostname `www.referrer.com` **[THEN]** respond with the contents of `C:\Your\File.txt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this in your FiddlerScript, in `OnBeforeRequest()`:

```
if (oSession.oRequest.headers.ExistsAndContains("Referer","www.referrer.com")) {
    if (oSession.uriContains("www.domain.com/file.js")) {
        oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
        oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Content-Type", "relevant/mime-type");
        oSession.ResponseBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Your\\File.txt");              
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. I might get a little time to read the documentation one day.

Comment: I have noticed that IE7 will baulk if correct mime types are not associated with CSS and JS. I have added an extra line to the answer to account for this.